# How do I find the makers that sell one type but not another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have to:

> Find the makers that sell PCs but not laptops.

This query is not outputting correct result:

```
SELECT maker, type FROM product
WHERE type = 'PC' AND type <> 'Laptop'
```

Output from this and correct output:

[image: output]

Result set from this query:

```
SELECT maker, type FROM product
```

[image: ex2]

Table schema:

[image: table]

Even this one is not working:

```
SELECT maker, type FROM product
WHERE type IN('PC') AND type NOT IN('Laptop')
```

NOTE - `type` is added just for clarification

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT maker
FROM product
GROUP BY maker
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: Why count? OP says `Find out the makers that sale PCs but not laptops. ` That means `Find makers that only sell PCs`

Comment: @Dukeling This is returning blank

Comment: Whoops, should've been `SUM` (fixed).

Comment: @BhavikShah Assuming your question still holds, the PC sum is = the number of PCs they sell, so check for > 0 means they sell PCs. The Laptop sum is = the number of Laptops they sell, so check for = 0 means they don't sell Laptops.

Comment: @Dukeling ..Perfect now :) ..thx a ton :) +1 and green label :)

Answer (score 8):

There are many exotic ways to solve this problem. Here, the first coming to mind :)

1. The trivial solution.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT maker
      FROM Product
        WHERE type = 'PC' AND maker NOT IN (
            SELECT maker
            FROM Product
            WHERE type = 'Laptop')
   ```
2. Using the `JOIN`

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT Pr.maker
   FROM Product AS Pr LEFT JOIN Product AS Pr2
       ON Pr.maker = Pr2.maker AND Pr2.type = 'Laptop'
   WHERE Pr.type = 'PC' AND Pr2.maker IS NULL
   ```
3. Using the `EXCEPT`.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT maker
       FROM product AS Pr1
       WHERE type = 'PC'
   EXCEPT
   SELECT DISTINCT Pr2.maker
       FROM product AS Pr2
       WHERE type = 'laptop'
   ```
4. Using the `DISTINCT` and `NOT EXISTS`.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT maker
   FROM Product AS PcP
   WHERE type = 'PC' AND
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker
                     FROM Product
                     WHERE type = 'laptop' AND
                     maker = PcP.maker
                    )
   ```
5. Using the `CASE` increment and `HAVING`.

   ```
   SELECT maker
       FROM product
   GROUP BY maker
   HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'PC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
      AND SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'Laptop' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
   ```
6. Using the `DISTINCT` and comparison subqueries

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT maker
   FROM Product AS Pr
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM Product AS Pt
          WHERE Pt.type = 'PC' AND Pt.maker = Pr.maker
         ) > 0 
       AND
         (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM Product AS Pt2
          WHERE Pt2.type = 'Laptop' AND
          Pt2.maker = Pr.maker
         ) = 0
   ```
7. Using `HAVING` and cheating (The `HAVING` can't contain columns without aggregate, so we use the senseless(in this case) aggregate `MIN` (or `MAX` - it does not matter)

   ```
   SELECT maker
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT maker, type
             FROM Product
             WHERE type IN ('PC', 'Laptop')
            ) AS T
   GROUP BY maker
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND MIN(type) = 'PC'
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Try this
**Find out the makers that sale PCs but not laptops.**

```
SELECT maker , type FROM product
WHERE type = 'PC' AND maker NOT IN 
( SELECT maker FROM product WHERE type = 'laptop' )
```

Comment: its working but have to use DISTINCT for explicit results, as it is creating duplicate result with this.. +1 for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct maker 
from product 
where type = 'PC'  
  and maker not in ( select maker from product where type = 'Laptop')
```

it works

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product AS pc_product
WHERE type = 'pc' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT maker 
                  FROM Product
                  WHERE type = 'laptop' AND 
                        maker = pc_product.maker
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

can i suggest that you try to trim the values in your where clause... there might be some errand spaces and therefore exact matches are not returning the desired result.

Like so:

```
SELECT maker , type FROM product
WHERE TRIM(type) = 'PC' AND TRIM(type) <> 'Laptop'
```

alternatively, you could simply try:

```
SELECT maker , type FROM product
WHERE TRIM(type) = 'PC'
```

If Laptop and PC are 2 seperate types, then just filter for PC.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below;

```
    Select maker from product where type in('PC','laptop')
    except
    select maker from product where type='laptop'
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct maker from product where type='PC' and maker not in (select maker from product where type='laptop')

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve the problem

```
Select maker from product
where type = 'PC'
Except
Select maker from product
where type = 'laptop'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Prd.maker as Maker
from   product as Prd INNER JOIN PC as P
ON     Prd.model = P.model
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM Laptop as L INNER JOIN Product as P
  ON L.model = P.model and Prd.maker = P.maker
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAKER FROM PRODUCT
WHERE TYPE IN ('PC') AND MAKER NOT IN
(SELECT MAKER FROM PRODUCT WHERE TYPE IN ('LAPTOP'))
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select maker from Product where type in('PC')
intersect
select maker from Product where type  in ('PC','Printer')
except
select maker from Product where type='Laptop'
```